# How is it possible that unrolling scotch tape in a vacuum causes X-rays?

Tags: classical-mechanics, particle-physics, experimental-physics

A fun kind of question...

In 2008, researchers at the UCLA's Department of Physics and Astronomy found that unrolling of scotch tape in a vacuum caused X-rays to be created.  First, energetic electrons were produced and then X-rays.   The study stated that 300,000 x-ray photons were produced and that they were bright enough to image a finger...   As Dr. Putterman stated "kind of a microscopic lighting effect"

So why does this happen???

Comment: It is a duplicate question.. but one never fully answered..."However, the researchers remain stumped as to how the diffuse mechanical energy needed to peel the tape is focused to the extent that it can produce X-rays, and even more strangely how it can do so in the form of nanosecond pulses."

Comment: I do not find it that strange. When one pulls charged surfaces apart, the potential difference increases. This might very well accelerate electrons and ions to keV energies.